# How do I publish a piece of data and then stop reacting to it?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to make a homepage where several pieces of data are published, but only when the user first visits the page : one would get the latest 10 articles published but that's it - it won't keep changing.

Is there a way to make the inbuilt pub/sub mechanism turn itself off after a set amount of time or number of records, or another mechanism?

Right now I'm using a very simple setup that doesn't "turn off":

```
latestNews = new Mongo.Collection('latestNews');

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.subscribe("latestNews");
}
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish('latestNews', function() {
    return latestNews.find({}, {sort: { createdAt: -1 }, limit : 10});
  });
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if this question contained a [mcve]...

Comment: Added some code per above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pub/sub pattern as it is implemented in Meteor is all about reactive data updates. In your case that would mean if the author or last update date of an article changes then users would see this change immediately reflected on their home page.

However you want to send data once and not update it ever again.
Meteor has a built-in functionality to handle this scenario : [Methods](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_methods). A method is a way for the client to tell the server to execute computations and/or send pure non-reactive data.

```
//Server code
var lastTenArticlesOptions = {
  sort : { 
    createdAt : -1
  },
  limit : 10
}

Meteor.methods({
  'retrieve last ten articles' : function() {
    return latestNews.find({}, lastTenArticlesOptions).fetch()
  }
})
```

Note that contrary to publications we do not send a [`Mongo.Cursor`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_cursor)! Cursors are used in publications as a handy (aka magic) way to tell the server which data to send.
Here, we are sending the data the data directly by `fetch`ing the cursor to get an array of articles which will then be [`EJSON.stringify`ied](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/ejson_stringify) automatically and sent to the client.

---

If you need to send reactive data to the client and at a later point in time to stop pushing updates, then your best bet is relying on a pub/sub temporarily, and then to manually `stop` the [publication](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/publish_stop) (server-side) or the [subscription](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_subscribe) (client-side) :

```
Meteor.publish('last ten articles', function() {
  return latestNews.find({}, lastTenArticlesOptions)
})
```

```
var subscription = Meteor.subscribe('last ten articles')
//Later...
subscription.stop()
```

On the server-side you would store the publication handle (`this`) and then manipulate it.

Stopping a subscription or publication does not destroy the documents already sent (the user won't see the last ten articles suddenly disappear).